# problem of using http address as params in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

i use a request like this in chrome and at the backend the param *baseUrl* resloved correct

```
http://192.168.227.100:15004/groundStations?baseUrl=http://192.168.227.100:15002/bases/f788cc05-81d3-4759-8acf-20eb8b0118ac
```

but this one

```
http://192.168.227.100:15004/planes?baseUrl=http://192.168.227.100:15002/bases/f788cc05-81d3-4759-8acf-20eb8b0118ac&jobGuideUrl=http://192.168.227.100:15003/jobGuides/jobGuide_A/versions/1.0
```

i got the param *baseUrl* at backend is *http://192.168.227.100:15002/bases/f788cc05-81d3-4759-8acf-20eb8b0118ac,f788cc05-81d3-4759-8acf-20eb8b0118ac*

only different is there is one more param *jobGuideUrl*

does someone know why?

Comment: and the second is worked by using postman for request

Comment: our front engineer made a small tiny mistake...